# What could cause me to periodically lose upload ability on a wired PC when I can still receive data?

Tags: networking, home-networking, connection, upload

I have been dealing with an issue on my home network where I cannot send/upload data for periods of time (1-30seconds). During this time, I can still receive data, I just cannot transmit. I have tested this on several PCs in the house (wired and wifi connected) and the results are identical.

This problem was first noticed when I would constantly get disconnected for several seconds at a time from online video games. The interesting thing is I could still hear my friends on discord and see other players' new commands being actively issued until the game disconnected me. Meanwhile, my friends could not hear me nor were my commands being acknowledged by the game.

I would greatly appreciate any knowledge of what could cause this kind of behavior. Let me know if there is any additional information you think could be useful.

---

For the past four days, I have run a ping log on PowerShell using PowerPing.
[This](https://www.dropbox.com/s/3oq7ry86rcf34yd/log-raw.txt?dl=0) shows my log unfiltered.
[This](https://www.dropbox.com/s/1fl76f37dz1gogi/log-only-errors.txt?dl=0) shows my log which has been filtered to show only unsuccessful pings.
Below is a sample of my unfiltered log.

```
Reply from: 8.8.8.8:0 seq=4301 bytes=38 type=ECHO REPLY time=15.1ms @ 13:25:13
Reply from: 8.8.8.8:0 seq=4302 bytes=38 type=ECHO REPLY time=15.1ms @ 13:25:14
Reply from: 8.8.8.8:0 seq=4303 bytes=38 type=ECHO REPLY time=19.0ms @ 13:25:15
Reply from: 8.8.8.8:0 seq=4304 bytes=38 type=ECHO REPLY time=15.0ms @ 13:25:16
Reply from: 8.8.8.8:0 seq=4305 bytes=38 type=ECHO REPLY time=13.9ms @ 13:25:17
Reply from: 8.8.8.8:0 seq=4306 bytes=38 type=ECHO REPLY time=18.8ms @ 13:25:18
Request timed out. seq=4307  @ 13:25:22
Request timed out. seq=4308  @ 13:25:26
Request timed out. seq=4309  @ 13:25:30
Reply from: 192.168.1.28:0 seq=4310 bytes=66 type=HOST UNREACHABLE time=2718.1ms @ 13:25:34
Request timed out. seq=4311  @ 13:25:38
Reply from: 8.8.8.8:0 seq=4312 bytes=38 type=ECHO REPLY time=21.3ms @ 13:25:39
Reply from: 8.8.8.8:0 seq=4313 bytes=38 type=ECHO REPLY time=21.4ms @ 13:25:40
Reply from: 8.8.8.8:0 seq=4314 bytes=38 type=ECHO REPLY time=14.3ms @ 13:25:41
Reply from: 8.8.8.8:0 seq=4315 bytes=38 type=ECHO REPLY time=15.3ms @ 13:25:42
Reply from: 8.8.8.8:0 seq=4316 bytes=38 type=ECHO REPLY time=13.8ms @ 13:25:43
Reply from: 8.8.8.8:0 seq=4317 bytes=38 type=ECHO REPLY time=15.2ms @ 13:25:44
Reply from: 8.8.8.8:0 seq=4318 bytes=38 type=ECHO REPLY time=18.4ms @ 13:25:45
Request timed out. seq=4319  @ 13:25:49
Request timed out. seq=4320  @ 13:25:53
Request timed out. seq=4321  @ 13:25:57
Reply from: 8.8.8.8:0 seq=4322 bytes=38 type=ECHO REPLY time=368.1ms @ 13:25:58
Reply from: 8.8.8.8:0 seq=4323 bytes=38 type=ECHO REPLY time=193.4ms @ 13:26:00
Reply from: 8.8.8.8:0 seq=4324 bytes=38 type=ECHO REPLY time=223.9ms @ 13:26:01
Reply from: 8.8.8.8:0 seq=4325 bytes=38 type=ECHO REPLY time=101.6ms @ 13:26:02
Reply from: 8.8.8.8:0 seq=4326 bytes=38 type=ECHO REPLY time=40.7ms @ 13:26:03
Reply from: 8.8.8.8:0 seq=4327 bytes=38 type=ECHO REPLY time=86.5ms @ 13:26:04
Reply from: 8.8.8.8:0 seq=4328 bytes=38 type=ECHO REPLY time=13.8ms @ 13:26:05
Reply from: 8.8.8.8:0 seq=4329 bytes=38 type=ECHO REPLY time=14.2ms @ 13:26:06
Reply from: 8.8.8.8:0 seq=4330 bytes=38 type=ECHO REPLY time=14.5ms @ 13:26:07
Reply from: 8.8.8.8:0 seq=4331 bytes=38 type=ECHO REPLY time=16.6ms @ 13:26:08
Reply from: 8.8.8.8:0 seq=4332 bytes=38 type=ECHO REPLY time=15.1ms @ 13:26:09
Reply from: 8.8.8.8:0 seq=4333 bytes=38 type=ECHO REPLY time=18.2ms @ 13:26:10
```

Comment: Run a second ping (at the same time) to your router (default gateway), to see if the problem is inside or outside your network.

Answer (score 0):

Ping only reports end to end.  Try **traceroute** (on linux/mac, or **tracert** on Windows) to see the timing on each hop.

If you see a really long response time on one of the middle servers/routers along the way, and it happens to be your ISP, it's possible they have a traffic shaper (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Traffic_shaping) managing your overall use of bandwidth (i.e. throttling your traffic for a moment whenever you go over some limit).

If you see the slow hop is close to the destination host (e.g. game server), they might be traffic shaping to balance their overall inbound load.

If it's within your own network, you might have a QoS service on your router that's set up to give too much priority to another type of traffic (maybe a video stream).

Comment: I used your suggestion and took it one step further by creating a ping log for each device shown in the traceroute. When my issue occurs, the pings make it to my default gateway, but timeout when pinging the next hop/device..

Since hop 1 is to my router and hop 2 is to a box owned by my ISP, this skips my cable modem because it doesn't have an IP address (that I know of).
**Is there anyway to tell whether the problem is with my router (hop 1), modem (which I can't ping), or my ISP's box in the street (hop 2)?**

Comment: Assuming your default gateway is also the LAN/router side of your cable modem, there will also be an IP (usually dynamically) assigned to the WAN/public side of that device, which you can discover by visiting a site like https://whatismyip.com . Sounds like you have isolated the blockage to the connection from your house to the ISP, so the next step is to have the provider (cable company) troubleshoot that connection using equipment that can detect issues with the physical cable or the termination equipment - See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cable_modem_termination_system